# Unit test when receiver method call each other

Tags: unit-testing, go

Imagine there is a `User` package which contains only two simple methods

1. `Hello` which says "Hello"
2. `Say` which implements how a user speaks

**Original**

```
package user

import "fmt"

type user struct {}

func (u user) Hello() {
    u.Say("Hello")
}

func (u user) Say(sentence string) {
    fmt.Println(sentence)
}
```

However, we are not able to unit test `Hello` since it depends on `Say` which is not mockable.

After searing on StackOverflow and Goole, I summarize two methods to solve the problem, but none of them are perfect.

**Method 1 - Use lambda func**

user.go

```
package user

import "fmt"

type user struct{}

func (u user) Hello() {
    say("Hello")
}

func (u user) Say(sentence string) {
    say(sentence)
}

var say = func(sentence string) {
    fmt.Println(sentence)
}
```

user_test.go

```
package user

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestHello(t *testing.T) {
    sayCalled := 0
    sayCallArg := ""

    mockSay := func(sentence string) {
        sayCalled++
        sayCallArg = sentence
    }
    say = mockSay

    u := user{}
    u.Hello()

    if sayCalled != 1 {
        t.Fatalf("not called")
    }
    if sayCallArg != "Hello" {
        t.Fatalf("wrong arg")
    }
}
```

**Method 2 - Use interface**

user.go

```
package user

import "fmt"

type user struct {
    sayer Sayer
}

func (u user) Hello() {
    u.sayer.Say("Hello")
}

func (u user) Say(sentence string) {
    u.sayer.Say(sentence)
}

type Sayer interface {
    Say(string)
}

type sayer struct{}

func (s sayer) Say(sentence string) {
    fmt.Println(sentence)
}
```

user_test.go

```
package user

import (
    "testing"
)

type mockSayer struct {
    called    int
    calledArg string
}

func (s *mockSayer) Say(sentence string) {
    s.called++
    s.calledArg = sentence
}

func TestHello(t *testing.T) {
    mockSayer := &mockSayer{}
    u := user{sayer: mockSayer}
    u.Hello()

    if mockSayer.called != 1 {
        t.Fatalf("not called")
    }
    if mockSayer.calledArg != "Hello" {
        t.Fatalf("wrong arg")
    }
}
```

I understand most of the cases, people will suggest to use Method 2 since that's how dependency injection works in Go.

However, in this example, it's weird to extract the implementation of `Say` to another layer (unnecessary complexity in my opinion).

Is there any better solution to solve this kind of dependency?
or which method you prefer and why?

Comment: By following your reasoning, we should test the integrity of each function at the order level.

We test the results of the function not the integral, so the test should check only the output of the function `Hello`.

Comment: When there is a function `Hello` and I need to test its correctness. Usually, I will do two things. The first one is to assert the correctness of the output (kind of black box test) and the second one is to assert calledCount and calledParams if `Hello` call any other function (kind of white box test).
The question is more focusing on how can we do the second one gracefully without impacting the normal development experience (two methods I summarize above are bad development experience due to unnecessary complexity)

Answer (score 2):

None of the above. I don't see where you prove that the `Hello` method actually works, that "`Hello\n`" is actually written. Check the `Say` method output. Mock `os.Stdout`. For example,

`user.go`:

```
package user

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

type user struct{}

const hello = "Hello"

func (u user) Hello() {
    u.Say(hello)
}

var stdwrite = io.Writer(os.Stdout)

func (u user) Say(sentence string) {
    fmt.Fprintln(stdwrite, sentence)
}
```

`user_test.go`:

```
package user

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "testing"
)

func TestHello(t *testing.T) {
    u := user{}

    u.Hello() // for real

    defer func(w io.Writer) { stdwrite = w }(stdwrite)
    stdwrite = new(bytes.Buffer)

    u.Hello() // for test

    got := stdwrite.(*bytes.Buffer).String()
    want := hello + "\n"
    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("want: %q got: %q", want, got)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -v
=== RUN   TestHello
Hello
--- PASS: TestHello (0.00s)
PASS
ok      say 0.001s
```

Comment: In my opinion, that's the responsibility of integration test to examine if the "`Hello\n`" being written because now the `Hello` depends on `Say`.

In unit test, we only care if the `Hello` truly calls `Say` and pass the correct parameters to it.

There is no need to understand the implementation detail of `Say` while doing unit test on `Hello`

Comment: Very interesting approach to intercept `stdout`. But Structly speaking this tests not method `Hello` itself, but a conjunction of `Hello`+`Say`. How to test hello itself?